# Ending a Game When Two Nodes Collide in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to make a flappy bird type game in Swift with SpriteKit. In my game instead of the game ending when the bird collies with the pipes I want the game to end when the bird leaves the screen. once the game is over I want it to go to a new screen. Here is the code I have so far.
    import SpriteKit

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var bird = SKSpriteNode()
    var pipeUpTexture = SKTexture()
    var pipeDownTexture = SKTexture()
    var PipeMoveAndRemove = SKAction()
    let pipeGap = 150.0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //Physics
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0);

        //Bird
        var BirdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"birdapp")
        BirdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: BirdTexture)
        bird.setScale(0.5)
        bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)

        bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:bird.size.height/2.0);
        bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        self.addChild(bird)

        //Ground
        var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"groundapp")
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        sprite.setScale(2.0)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0, sprite.size.height/2.0)

        self.addChild(sprite)

        var ground = SKNode()

        ground.position = CGPointMake(0, groundTexture.size().height)
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))

        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(ground)

        //Pipes

        //create the pipes
        pipeUpTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"pipeupapp")
        pipeDownTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"pipedownapp")

        //move pipes
        let distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUpTexture.size().width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove))
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        PipeMoveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes, removePipes])

        //spwan pipes
        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnPipes()})
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
        let spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        let spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)
        self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)
    }

    func spawnPipes(){
        let pipePair = SKNode()
        pipePair.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + pipeUpTexture.size().width * 2, 0)
        pipePair.zPosition = -10

        let height = UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 4)
        let y = arc4random() % height + height

        let pipeDown = SKSpriteNode(texture:pipeDownTexture)
        pipeDown.setScale(2.0)
        pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y) + pipeDown.size.height + CGFloat(pipeGap))

        pipeDown.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:pipeDown.size)
        pipeDown.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        pipePair.addChild(pipeDown)

        let pipeUp = SKSpriteNode(texture:pipeUpTexture)
        pipeUp.setScale(2.0)
        pipeUp.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y))

        pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeUp.size)
        pipeUp.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        pipePair.addChild(pipeUp)

        pipePair.runAction(PipeMoveAndRemove)
        self.addChild(pipePair)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 20))
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: In your update loop, you can check to see if your bird is still visible.  if it's not, run your game over function.  What have you tried though?  What issues are you having?

Comment: Having trouble linking when its not seen to the game over screen

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do.  It's not code you can copy paste directly into your game.  But it's easy to understand, and you should be able to modify it to suit your needs

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let bird: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    var gameOver = false

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        self.bird.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(self.bird)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func endGame(){
        // restart the game
        let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        self.view!.presentScene(gameScene)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {


        // our bird doesnt intersect the frame, 
        // we use gameOver bool so we dont call endGame more than once
        if !self.frame.intersects(self.bird.frame) && !self.gameOver{
            self.gameOver = true
            self.endGame()
        }

    }

}
```